# error: conflicting return type specified, different than usual

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm a computer science student. I know "conflicting return type specified" usually means you're using a function before it's declared but this one is a little different. Due to strict assignment guidelines, I'm implementing a task scheduler (our own multi-threader) and in one class called `Task`, in `Task.h` we have :

```
void Task::Start(){
    int * returnval = new int;
    *returnval = pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,tfunc,this);        
    delete returnval;
}
```

then in another file, `schedulable.h`, we have:

```
int Schedulable::Start(){ 
    try{ 
        Task::Start();
        return 0; 
    }catch(int e) { return 1; } 
}
```

When I compile it, I have a "conflicting return type" error:

```
In file included from scheduler.H:59, from task_test_step2.cpp:9: schedulable.H:162: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual int Schedulable::Start()’ task.h:157: error: overriding ‘virtual void Task::Start()’
```

Any ideas how I can get this to stop happening?

Comment: At which line is the actual error occuring?  And can you paste the real error message, not a synopsis of it?

Comment: What is the relationship between `Task` and `Schedulable`? If `Task` is inherited from `Schedulable`, then you have two `Start`s with conflicting return type, which of course is an error. The reason why is that if you have an object of `Schedulable` and call its `Start` the compiler gets confused.

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: @Shahbaz: I bet you're right; you should post that as an answer. (Though I assume that `Schedulable` inherits from `Task`, and not the other way around.)

Comment: oops here

`In file included from scheduler.H:59,
                 from task_test_step2.cpp:9:
schedulable.H:162: error: conflicting return type specified for ‘virtual int Schedulable::Start()’
task.h:157: error:   overriding ‘virtual void Task::Start()’`

Comment: @Shahbaz: The full error message that just arrived in the comments says you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `Schedulable::Start` overrides `Task::Start` and changes the return type from `void` to `int`. You probably want to make `Task::Start` return an int too:

```
int Task::Start(){
    // no need to use new here!
    int returnval = pthread_create(&thread_id,NULL,tfunc,this);        
    return returnval;
}
```

Comment: alrighty, I figured it'd come down to that, we're instructed to not change header files unless we can document good reason to do so, so I was just making sure there was no alternative. Thanks, I really appreciate it!